Issue solving 2-3 B-tree
I do not know how to delete the node 90 from this 2-3 B-tree
and i cant put in a simulator because i would need to replicate the tree exactly and I do not know how to do that. I would really appreciate the help.
I have tried replicating the tree on a simulator but cant.

It looks like you are using the simulator by David Galles, University of San Francisco, or a similar one.
Insert the values in this order:
0004 0010 0015 0024 0040 0074 0090
0020 0019 0016

The result will be:

The procedure to delete 0090 from that tree:

The value is deleted from the relevant node, leaving it without values.

The sibling node has no values to spare, so the empty node is deleted, and the value 0074 is taken away from the parent node and added to the sibling node (which now has values 0040 0074. Now that parent node has no values.

This time the sibling node (having 0010 and 0019) has a value to spare, so we can perform a rotation (in clockwise direction):

The parent value (0024) is moved down to the empty node, making the root empty.
The right-most value in the sibling node (0019) is moved up to the root, and the now orhpaned leaf (0020) is attached to the node that received 0024.



The result:

